# I need the part name or description of below U12 i the PCB

Tags: microchip

I need the part name or description the U12 in the PCB highlighted.[image]

Comment: what does the board do?

Comment: The board is hondata kpro use to control the engine control unit

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a Diodes Incorporated 74LVC1T45W6-7. Image from [lcsc](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Buffer-Driver-Transceiver_Diodes-Incorporated-74LVC1T45W6-7_C168856.html) which also links to DI datasheet.

[image]

[image]